# How do I get the "Installed a medium" prompt to go away?

Tags: devices

When I plug my Kindle into the USB port, I get an annoying popup that says:

> You have just installed a medium. Select how to open kindle and whether to perform this action in the future for other media of type 'e-book reader.

"Ask what to do, Do Nothing, or Open Folder." with a check-box option that says "Always perform this action.

I'm new, but I'm not dead. There are many options without getting and thus having to deal with this prompt:

1. Click on stick icon on the side-bar which in this case means Kindle,
2. Get it from the Dash,
3. Get to it from Files icon on sidebar, and
4. Type a prompt in the terminal to open it.

Bottom line?  Why is it there and how do I make this popup prompt go away for faster, more streamlined computing?

Comment: Select "do nothing" and check "always preform this action"?

Comment: I don't understand the so many downvotes here. It is a simple newbie question. Maybe the answer is obvious, but it is still a question. It is not a spam or rant(well maybe a little bit) or anything else to justify so many downvotes.

Comment: I don't understand the so many downvotes here. It is a simple newbie question. Maybe the answer is obvious, but it is still a question. It is not a spam or rant(well maybe a little bit) or anything else to justify so many downvotes. –  NikTh Jan 1 '14 at 6:48...........................................................Thank you NikTh, for your support.  You get kudo votes from me!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on settings of your external device Ubuntu may recognize it's purposed content (i.e. a digital camera will contain photos, an mp3-player will contain music, and an e-book reader will contain e-books).

We can define default applications to open the drive whenever the application chosen has  support of this.

To change these default application we can go to *System Settings...* to choose the *Details* cogwheel.

[image]

In the "Removable Media" section we will have predefined applications for the most common media types but there also is an <kbd>Other Media...</kbd> button for more types. Amongst these we also may find the type "E-book reader" from where we can define default actions on inserting it to our computer.

It is there where we can also define the application to open the media, or to choose *"Do nothing"* in case we don't want to be bothered.